# c struct in multiple file error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, types, struct

I am trying to declare a struct and use it in multiple files and I am getting an error that I cannot figure out. Sample code is posted below.

in test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

struct mystruct;
struct mystruct *new_mystruct();
void myprint(struct mystruct*,int);

#endif
```

int test.c

```
#include "test.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct mystruct {
    int *myarray;
};

struct mystruct *new_mystruct(int length)
{
    int i;

    struct mystruct *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
    s->myarray = malloc(length*sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        s->myarray = 2*i;

    return s;
}
```

in main.c

```
#include "test.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int len = 10;

    struct mystruct *c = new_mystruct(len);
    myprint(c, len);

    printf("%f", c->myarray[3]); // error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

    return 0;
```

myprint() prints out 0  2  4  6  8  10 12  14  16  18. why doesn't the myprint(function work but the printf statement doesn't? why is it ok to pass it into a function but not use it in main? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `main()` only knows that `struct mystruct` is a type, but it doesn't know anything about its internal structure, because you've hidden it in test.c.

So you need to move this definition:

```
struct mystruct {
    int *myarray;
};
```

from test.c to test.h, so that it's visible to `main()`.

Note: what you're doing here is a classic example of an *opaque type*. This can be a very useful technique when you want to hide implementation details from code that is going to be calling your API.

Comment: I was trying to hide the contents of the struct from test.h. Is this not possible?

Comment: Sure - what you're doing is fine, but if you hide the implementation in test.c then no other source files (e.g. main.c) can see it, so you may need to provide other functions (getters, setters, etc) if you want other code to be able to do anything useful with your API.

Comment: Thanks. I added a get_myarray function in test.c that returns the array and called it in main before the printf and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Main.c doesn't know the contents of the mystruct structure.  Try moving these lines:

```
struct mystruct {
    int *myarray;
};
```

from test.c to test.h.

While you're at it, I think you mean "int myarray" not "int *myarray".

Comment: No, I think he means `int *myarray` - it's a dynamically allocated array - see `new_mystruct()`.